# How to change multiple checkboxes with Blazor when clicking one of them

Tags: blazor

Part 1:

I got the onchange to work with:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="@ShowMe" @onchange="(e => ChangeBox(e, 13))" />
```

and in the code part I have:

```
protected bool ShowMe { get; set; } = true;

private void ChangeBox(ChangeEventArgs e, int id)
{

}
```

When clicking the checkbox I get into the event handler so that works out. However when opening the page on the first load the checkbox is not selected even though ShowMe is set to true.

Part 2:

What I'm trying to get to is a foreach to make a table with several columns being checkboxes like this:

```
Concern    Phase 1     Phase 2     Phase 3
1          false       false       false
2          false       false       false
2          false       false       false
2          false       false       false
3          false       false       false
```

now when I click on a checkbox in column Phase 1 for Concern 2 then all 3 checkboxes should become true like:

```
Concern    Phase 1     Phase 2     Phase 3
1          false       false       false
2          true        false       false
2          true        false       false
2          true        false       false
3          false       false       false
```

I bind to `private ConcernData[] data`

which is made up of

```
public class ConcernData
{
    public int Concern { get; set; }
    public bool Phase1 { get; set; }
    public bool Phase2 { get; set; }
    public bool Phase3 { get; set; }
}
```

And fetched via an HttpClient Get call.

Comment: What about Phase 2  and  Phase 3 ? Do you also want similar behavior ? I guess when  I click on a checkbox in column Phase 1 for Concern 3 only  the checkbox for Concern 3  should be true, right ?

Comment: Use Linq request to get the corresponding `ConcernData` and update it : `var concern = data.First(c => c.Concern == id); concern.Phase1 = concern.Phase2 = concern.Phase3 = true;`

Comment: @enet those should act the same but for their respective column.

Comment: @aguafrommars I know how to handle linq, that's not the issue. What's not working out for me is the handling (or how to set it up) of the Blazor parts for binding and capturing the onchange event in the case a checkbox gets clicked/changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this code and see if that is what you want. Note: When you check either of the second third or fourth checkbox, the three of them are checked, no matter the order...

```
@page "/"

<table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Concern</td>
                <td>Phase1</td>
                <td>Phase2</td>
                <td>Phase3</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var row in data.Rows)
            {
            <tr>
                <td><label>@row.Concern</label></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" checked="@row.Phase1" @onchange="@((args) => { row.Phase1 = (bool)
        args.Value; Check(row.Concern, row.Phase1);  } )" />
                </td>
                <td><input type="checkbox"  @bind="@row.Phase2" /></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox"  @bind="@row.Phase3" /></td>
               
            </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

@code{


    ConcernData data = new ConcernData();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {

    }

    protected void Check(int row,  bool selectedValue)
    {
      var toCheck =  data.Rows.Where(r => r.Concern == row).ToList();
      foreach (var r in toCheck)
      {
         r.Phase1 = selectedValue;
      }
    }

    public class Row
    {
        public int Concern { get; set; }
        public bool Phase1 { get; set; }
        public bool Phase2 { get; set; }
        public bool Phase3 { get; set; }
    }

    public class ConcernData
    {
        public List<Row> Rows = new List<Row> { new Row { Concern = 1, Phase1 = false, Phase2 = false, Phase3 = false },
                                         new Row { Concern = 2, Phase1 = false, Phase2 = false, Phase3 = false },
                                         new Row { Concern = 2, Phase1 = false, Phase2 = false, Phase3 = false },
                                         new Row { Concern = 2, Phase1 = false, Phase2 = false, Phase3 = false },
                                         new Row { Concern = 3, Phase1 = false, Phase2 = false, Phase3 = false }};


    }

}
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind checked attribute not value for a checkbox:

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked="@ShowMe" @onchange="(e => ChangeBox(e, 13))" />
```

Ref : https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/InputCheckbox.cs