# How to pass actionable control characters from a JSON text element to a razor component Blazor variable

Tags: json, razor, blazor, razor-pages, blazor-server-side

I want to read a JSON text string that contains control characters into a razor component Blazor variable.
The Blazor variable is:

```
<p>@Product.Description</p>
```

I want the JSON text to include control characters that enable the string to be formatted for display. I have used HTML <br> tags in an example JSON text string showing what I want below.

```
"Description": "This is a detailed description.<br> There is also a list of bullet points, for example:<br>●  Helpful hints;<br>●  Links to other sites.”
```

Unfortunately, the <br> tags are rendered as text and not line breaks.  I have also tried \r\n and various other escape sequences but are all rendered as text.
Can anyone tell me how to pass actionable control characters from a JSON text element to a razor component Blazor variable please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<p>@((MarkupString)Product.Description)</p>
```

Comment: No, he won't. He has almost never accepted answers. See his history.  ( Presently, I check the history of the OP before answering.) This attitude is typical among many participants in stackoverflow.  And no wonder, if the moderator on the ASP.NET forums serves as a role model. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62660744/6152891

Comment: Peter, I apologize for the slow acceptance.  Sometimes it takes me some time to get back to the keyboard (I also don't accept answers that don't solve my problem).